# Dell Poweredge R710 memory mode

Tags: memory, dell-poweredge

Dell Poweredge R710 offers 16GB memory (4x4GB) in Advanced ECC mode for two processes.

Can I reconfigure it as Optimized mode in BIOS, even though apparently each socket only has two channels populated with one DIMM each?  In other words, does Optimized mode requires all three channels populated?

I came to the above speculation according to
http://lists.us.dell.com/pipermail/linux-poweredge/2009-May/039329.html
and its linked 
www.delltechcenter.com/page/04-08-2009+-+Nehalem+and+Memory+Configurations

Comment: Blog post that goes into some detail on memory configuration in the R710 if you are interested at http://blog.serverfault.com/post/know-your-ram/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nothing to do with Dell specifically but to do with the optimal triple-channel memory configuration of those Xeon 55/56xx-series chips - and no, you need all three memory channels in play for what Dell call their 'optimised' mode, it's not a BIOS thing, it's a 'using all available memory bandwidth' thing.

Unless you need the extra memory go for 12GB (3 x 4GB) over 16GB (4 x 4GB), or stump up for 24GB (6 x 4GB or 3 x 8GB) if you have the moolah :)

Comment: Thanks.  We went with 24GB (6 x 4GB) as the sales rep provided a terrific deal.